# Objective C array "key" instead of index

Tags: objective-c, arrays, indexing, key

I want to be able to use `NSString`, or something similar to store an array of strings, but access them by a key (I think this is what it's called), instead of a numeric index.

For example, instead of doing this:

```
return names[3];
```

Do something like this:

```
return names["Bob"];
```

How do you store and retrieve values like this?

Please excuse my lack of knowledge of this. I've been working with Objective C for about a year now, but never had to do anything like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Objective-C,  you do this with the `NSDictionary` class and its mutable subclass `NSMutableDictionary`. You can get the value for a key using

```
NSString *value = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"Bob"];
```

Answer (score 2):

[`NSDictionary`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

Those kind of arrays are taken from `C` (of which `Objective-C` is a superset) which only allow integers as their indices.

You may wish to use `NSDictionary` and it's `objectWithKey` style messages.

Comment: Arrays inherently are always by index.... name an array in a language that ultimately isn't? (Out of curiosity)

Comment: @bbum My knowledge of php is limited.. but php?

Comment: "An array in PHP is actually an ordered map." i.e. it is a dictionary with a determinate key order.  That is called an array is, frankly, odd.   Without exhaustive research, it appears to be more akin to Ruby's Hashes in that the elements are ordered by order of insertion, but it is still a true map/dictionary behind the scenes.